# Access Json Object rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, undefined

I am trying to create an instance variable that contains the list of URLs in the given JSON Return from that call (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=World&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=json)

In the first instance when i accessing the object individually using i get the correct value. If however iterate to get multiple values i am getting.

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) error

```
 @links=[] 
@description= @data_hash["query"]["pages"]["-1"]["imageinfo"][0]["url"] #Works ok
url = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=World&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=json")
  uri = URI(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  @data_hash= JSON.parse(response)
 ["url"]
 @data_hash["query"]["pages"].map { |i|

    i.map { |e|
       @links<< e['imageinfo'][0]
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@links = @data_hash['query']['pages']
           .values
           .map { |page| page['imageinfo'].first['url'] }
```